# need help looping add_action in wp

Tags: loop, actions

i would like to know the proper way to do this

```
$dynValue=5;//loop this many times
//start of my loop
for ($num=1; $num <= $dynValue; $num++){

//note the incremented number ($num) in the call back
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'mpc_meta_box_'.$num.');

//below is where im having the problem
// i am trying to increment this function name so i will not get the error that "function name has already been declared". i cannot add '.$num.' in the func name below cause its not valid php.
function mpc_meta_box_'.$num.'(){
//some content
}

}//end of my loop
```

i can do this with eval() but i know its not recommeneded

Comment: May I ask you why you want dynamic functions? What content will you put there when you don't know how many functions you need?

Comment: Which solution did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$dynValue=5;//loop this many times
//start of my loop
for ($num=1; $num <= $dynValue; $num++){
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', create_function('', '//some content'));
    // Write the php code as if it was to put it in an echo/print instruction.
    // More details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php
}//end of my loop
```

Comment: `create_function()` should never be used. It breaks object caches and it is hard to debug (and to read …).

Comment: Thanks toscho for this precision, I never use this function but I believed it would be practical here. I will continue not to use it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use always the same function as callback. You may use a static variable inside of the function to track how often it was called:

```
for ($num=1; $num <= $dynValue; $num++) 
{
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mpc_meta_box' );
}

function mpc_meta_box()
{
    static $counter = 1;
    echo $counter;
    counter++;
}
```

But I think you need to find a better architecture.